# Drupal 7 - Taxonomy terms based on pages?

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

No idea if this is the best way to do this but here is what i'm thinking.

I have a content type called 'Widgets' and each widget is a little piece of content. I wish to then have a generic 'View' which goes off and grabs all the widgets for the current page that the user is on.

Here is how I see it working in my head.. just not sure how to do it.

-When creating a content 'widget' the admin can somehow select a page they want it to appear on from a list taxonomy terms based on the site structure (as new pages are added they are also added to this tree automatically somehow)

-When a user then browses a page the generic view then works out what page the user is on and fetches all the widgets that have been tagged with this current page

Is this possible? and if so can someone please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, in the fields for the main pages you can add a term reference field that allows you to enter a new tag into the vocabulary.

The 'widget' content type can then select this new tag using a term select field. My view then automatically displays it because it is related.